# Does multicast over tunnels (e.g., GRE) require IGMP/MLD?

Tags: ipsec, multicast, gre, igmp

When subscribing to a multicast group on a tunnel device such as a GRE tunnel, are you supposed to participate in IGMP/MLD over that tunnel in order to announce your membership in the multicast group? If so, is this merely a SHOULD or is it a MUST? Any RFC citations would be much appreciated!

Comment: Not all tunnels support multicast. For example, IPSec does not.

Comment: Ah, that's good to know, thanks! Do you know other protocols (besides GRE) which do?

Comment: The usual implementation is to tunnel multicast in GRE, and then tunnel the GRE inside other tunnel protocols, such as IPSec.

Comment: Of course, the tunnel in a tunnel really cuts down on the MTU.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense. Are there any other tunneling protocols besides GRE that support multicast?

Comment: @joshlf Cisco's VTI (virtual tunnel interface) on IOS and IOS-XE do support multicast, even when equipped  with an IPsec profile (`tunnel mode ipsec ipv4` ; in this tunnel mode, traffic selectors for encryption default to 0.0.0.0/0 on both ends.), and you can use the VTI interfaces for both mutlicast based dyn. routing protocols (such as OSPF or EIGRP) and run PIM to establish PIM neighborship across them and use them to forward multicast. 

I haven't tried, but I think you could also send an IGMP join from one or the other side - but that would probably be a corner case.